# strncat function c++ not working

Tags: c++, string

I need to write void strncat which appends the first num characters of source to destination, plus a terminating null-character. If the length of the C string in source is less than num, only the content up to the terminating null-character is copied. What am i doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int MAXDESTINATION = 40;
const int MAXSOURCE = 150;
int main() {
char dest[MAXDESTINATION + 1] = "It don't mean a thing";
char src[MAXSOURCE + 1] = " if it don't got the Go-Go swing!";

int a = strlen(dest);
int b = strlen(src);
strncat(dest, src, MAXDESTINATION - a) ;}

void strncat(char destination[], const char source[], int num) {
if (int strlen(source) < num) {
    int begin = 0;
    bool less = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <num; i++) {
        if (destination[i] == '\0') {
            begin = i;
            less = true;
        }
        if (less == true) {
            destination[begin] = source[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume your talking about your compiler error? Because the code as you show will not build. If posting questions about build errors, always include the complete and unedited build output in the question body, and mark the lines of code where the error is (with e.g. a comment).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "If the length of the C string in source is less than num, only the content up to the terminating null-character is copied"  Doesn't sound like a compiler error

Comment: I dont' know what `if (int strlen(source) < num)` does, but you don't want the `int` in there.  That looks like a function declaration, but I can't imagine that being legal.

Comment: @xaxxon And that's what I meant. The code as shown will not build.

Comment: i'm sorry it didn't allow me to post the #include <iostream> and stuff because it didn't count as code?

Comment: You haven't even provided a complete listing for strncat -- it's missing at least a } but quite possibly more

Comment: i just edited it now and posted the full code that i have that didn't compile

Comment: that's great.  thank you.

Comment: You're not allowed to make your own function with the same name as standard library functions - change to `my_strncat` or something

Comment: it's still saying there's no declared identifier and thank you for your comment it actually did help remove the other compile error

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing (since you haven't provided even the full definition of strncat) your problem is that you're not incrementing begin.  The way it's written right now, the same spot is overwritten each time with the value at source[i]

You maybe want to say

```
        destination[begin++] = source[i];
```

or maybe you should just use `i` instead, as begin should probably track `i` exactly, as it's initialized to i and then should be incremented once every time i is.

Also, from an efficiency standpoint, you're iterating over `source` multiple times.  Once with your call to strlen (which has to go through each letter in the string to count them) and then again in your for loop.   You should look to remove the strlen.

Comment: Alright thanks i will try that and I will take out the int for strlen(source)

Comment: why doesn't this allow me to cout << strncat(dest, src, MAXDESTINATION - a) << endl;

Comment: your strncat returns void.  You can't print out a void.

Comment: Thank you so much i took out the cout but when i tried to debug it it said that there were build errors still even though it's not preventing the build itself

Comment: You'll need to post the updated code along with the specific compiler errors.   You can either make another question or add the new code to the bottom of your question you already have.   don't modify the original code or none of the comments/answers will make sense.

Comment: Sorry that's my bad i am new to this website and okay i will post a new question right now with the compile errors

Comment: I actually have already reached my question limit for right now :( so i will post the compile errors

Answer (score -1):

Compile errors:

error C1075 :end of file found before the left brace '{' ...

error c4996: 'strncat': this function or variable may be unsafe. consider using strncat_s instead.

Comment: instead of posting an answer, click the edit button at the bottom ofyour question and add this there.  We need to see the new code that is generating this error, though.   Also, you shouldnt name your function strncat -- name it like.. "my_strncat" or something

Comment: sorry i didn't know what you meant because i already edited it before. The one that is posted is my edited code that shows these compile errors